# How to make ultrasonic and light sensors detect whether a person moving in or out

Tags: variables, photoresistor, ultrasonics

I am trying to make a circuit that will be used for turning on a light whenever there are 1 or more people in a room. I need to add to a variable counter when someone enters and subtract when someone leaves. However, I do not know how to use the ultrasonic sensor for this purpose. What can I do?

Comment: Google. If you know how to use the Ultrasonic sensor and know the C++ basics, this will be very easy.

Comment: How do you find out whether the person is entering or exiting

Comment: Is there some distance change thing

Comment: You'd have to place two Sensors next door, and if both are triggered, someone got in or out. You can check whether the person went in or out by looking what Sensor was triggered first.

Comment: thanks for the help

Comment: but it will always detect some distance so I need to check if the distance is less than a certain amount

Comment: Yes, you have to expermient a little bit with it to find the best value.

Comment: Unless the person swings his hand around

Comment: Then you'd have to use a camera + Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123919/discussion-between-nineplustenequalstwentyone-and-python-schlange).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/ryanchan/room-occupancy-counter-3b3ffa?ref=part&ref_id=10308&offset=2) tutorial on the Arduino Projecthub, that project was already made. [Here](https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/ultrasonic-sensor-hc-sr04/) is a tutorial how to use a Ultrasonic sensor.